# How to dump the content of <WebElement>list without using for loop

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to write the contents of the list into a file using for loop. Is it possible to dump the entire content of the list with one single statement? Currently it is very slow. I want to speed up the program.

```
By getChanges = By.xpath("//td[contains(@class,'blob-code blob-code-addition') or contains(@class,'blob-code blob-code-deletion')]");

List<WebElement> listChanges = driver.findElements(getChanges);

for (int count = 0; count < listChanges.size(); count++) {

    String codeChanges=driver.findElements(getChanges).get(count).getText();

    outputHandle.write(codeChanges);
}
```

To add some more details, when I am on this page https://github.com/SunriseSoftVN/qlkh/commit/a8b1c3a241ccf83f33819f4b04a8d647238bdaf8#diff-33c32c1890dcfb06827b5db4bee85959

ListChanges size is :3408 and it gets stuck there like forever..I mean it takes a lot of time..It does not go into infinite loop as the file is getting written properly as expected.

Adding more code to show two cascaded for loops being used. The outer loop fails in the second iteration with error that the content on the page has changed even though it has not. This happens only when I replace the call to findElements with listChanges.

```
By getCommitList = By.xpath("//a[contains(@class,'sha button-outline')]");

                List<WebElement> commitList = driver.findElements(getCommitList);

//              System.out.println("ListChanges size is :" + commitList.size());

                for(int commitCount = 0; commitCount < commitList.size(); commitCount++)
                {
                    String commitName=driver.findElements(getCommitList).get(commitCount).getText(); //works but redundant call

//                  String commitName=commitList.get(commitCount).getText();

                    System.out.println(commitName);

//                  commitList.get(commitCount).click();  //suggested improvement but fails

                    driver.findElements(getCommitList).get(commitCount).click();

                    By getChanges = By.xpath("//td[contains(@class,'blob-code blob-code-addition') or contains(@class,'blob-code blob-code-deletion')]");

                    List<WebElement> listChanges = driver.findElements(getChanges);

                System.out.println("ListChanges size is :" + listChanges.size());

                    for (int count = 0; count < listChanges.size(); count++) {

//                      System.out.println(driver.findElements(getChanges).get(count).getText());  //prints all the code changes associated with each commit

//                      String codeChanges=driver.findElements(getChanges).get(count).getText();

                        String codeChanges=listChanges.get(count).getText();

//                      System.out.println("Writing code changes into file now *********");

                        outputHandle.write(codeChanges);

                        outputHandle.write("\n");

                    }
                    //AFTER FINISHING FIRST COMMIT, YOU MOVE TO THE NEXT COMMIT ON PREVIOUS PAGE

                    driver.navigate().back();
```

Adding the error message below:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
Command duration or timeout: 14 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html
```

Comment: What's `driver.navigate().back();` for here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you code does this:

- Find all the elements
- Find all the elements again
- Write the first element
- Find all the elements again
- Write the second element
- Find all the elements again
- Write the third element
- ...etc

```
String codeChanges=driver.findElements(getChanges).get(count).getText();
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See that call to `driver.findElements`? That finds all the elements... each time around the loop.

You probably want to replace that with `listChanges` to use the results of the search you did before.

Comment: Thanks! It works. But I have two cascaded for loops . This one was the inner one. When I try to substitute the call to findElements with listChanges, in the outer loop, it fails in the second iteration. It says the content on page has changed whereas it has not.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @immibis. Just as a proof I tested the code with following changes on `Chrome`

```
By getChanges = By.xpath("//td[contains(@class,'blob-code blob-code-addition') or contains(@class,'blob-code blob-code-deletion')]");

List<WebElement> listChanges = driver.findElements(getChanges);

for (int count = 0; count < listChanges.size(); count++) {

  String codeChanges = listChanges.get(count).getText();

  System.out.println(codeChanges);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Yes it works for the inner loop but the outer loop fails. Seems to lose context when it comes back for the second iteration.

Comment: @Zack Yes This is very common in `Selenium` and this happens due to `DOM` refresh. The only thing, to avoid this situation that I know, is to find the element on the fly which you had been doing and, unfortunately that's a performance issue in this case. Refer to [this](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp). I am really not sure what can be done to handle this situation. I will look into and see if anything can be done

Comment: If I replace this line driver.findElements(getCommitList).get(commitCount).click(); with commitList.get(commitCount).click(); it fails

Comment: Also, the content of the page has not changed. Its just that when I use this variable commitList, it does not work.

Comment: @Zack Is the code block you provided is complete? And, is the `url` still same?

Comment: Yes. it is complete and the url is same

Comment: @Zack Can you please verify the `url`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70986/discussion-between-zack-and-saifur).

Answer (score 0):

On each iteration you're navigating to a single commit list. Once on that commit list page, you're iterating through all the commit details in that list.

You can't cache the group of commit lists to a variable since you're navigating away from the page on each iteration. However, you don't need to lookup the entire group of links each time. You only need to lookup the list link you're going to click on.

```
String listSearchXPath = "//a[contains(@class,'sha button-outline')]";

// Count how many commit lists we need to lookup
int commitListSize = driver.findElements(By.xpath(listSearchXPath)).size()
System.out.println("ListChanges size is :" + commitListSize);

for(int commitCount = 0; commitCount < commitListSize; commitCount++)
    {
        // Lookup the link we're going to click on by adding an  
        // XPath index filter for the current iteration
        WebElement linkToClick = driver.findElement(By.xpath(listSearchXPath + "[" + commitCount.ToString + "]"));

        System.out.println(linkToClick.getText());

        // Click on the link. We're navigating to a new page
        // so we cannot reference this element again.
        linkToClick.click();

        // Do a new search for the details in the commit list
        List<WebElement> listChanges = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[contains(@class,'blob-code blob-code-addition') or contains(@class,'blob-code blob-code-deletion')]"));

        System.out.println("ListChanges size is :" + listChanges.size());

        // Iterate through the details and log to a file
        for (int count = 0; count < listChanges.size(); count++) {

            // We're still on the same page so we can reference our saved element
            // instead of doing a new search.
            String codeChanges = listChanges.get(count).getText();

            outputHandle.write(codeChanges + "\n");
    }

    //AFTER FINISHING FIRST COMMIT, YOU MOVE TO THE NEXT COMMIT ON PREVIOUS PAGE
    driver.navigate().back();
}
```